# How enumerate all device objects?

Tags: windows, drivers, setupapi

Sorry for my English.
I want to enumerate all pointers to the DEVICE_OBJECT's in the system. I know that this can be done from the user mode, but I forgot. May be with helping of ZwQueryDirectiryObject or SetupAPI..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NtQueryDirectoryObject`, but that doesn't give you pointers to the `DEVICE_OBJECT`s. Try opening the device objects and then enumerating handles using `NtQuerySystemInformation` to get the pointers.